# Spartan 6 SP605 VHDL external ram usage?

Tags: storage, vhdl, ram, spartan

I'm new to using VHDL and have run into an issue with my project. I'm trying to make an FPGA to converts from one communication protocol to a different one, and for this purpose it would be useful to be able to store (hopefully multiple) packets before converting.

Before I tried to store this data in arrays, but it became quickly apparent that this takes up far too much space on the FPGA. Therefore, I have been searching for a way to store the data on the DDR3 ram on the SP605 board (http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/xtp067_sp605_schematics.pdf, page 9). I however cannot find instructions on how to write or read data from this. I'm trying to store one 8bit std_logic_vector per clock cycle to later be accessed.

Can anyone advise me on how to proceed?

Comment: Do you have a Xilinx ISE/Vivado license to use basic IP cores?

Comment: [Spartan-6 FPGA Memory Controller User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug388.pdf) (UG388), plus of course the two for the sample implementation board you have, UG526 and UG527.

Comment: I do, so I should be able to use basic IP cores.

Thank you for the link, I'll be reading up on this and UG486 to see if I can implement something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xilinx offers an IP Core generator. This IP catalog contains a Memory Interface Generator (MIG) which generates an IP Core to access different memory types. Configure this core for DDR3.

Writing a DDR3 controller in VHDL is not a project for a beginner not even for an experienced designer. 
The state machine is simple and well known, but the calibration logic is very costly.

You should consider a caching or burst read/write technique, because DDR memory can not be accessed in every cycle.

Comment: And [Virtex-6 FPGA Memory Interface Solutions User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/mig/v3_92/ug406.pdf) (UG486), which tells you how to do it start.

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I'll now begin reading up on how to generate IP cores and going thorough these documents.